# The word "dann" often takes first position in a normal statement sentence, is it inversion?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

I noticed when a sentence or clause starts with *dann*, then the subject is inverted.
But I don't know if German uses it in that way to emphasis the time or if it's an exception of the language. Is there any case it's placed after verb?

Comment: Plenty of cases: *Er steht dann auf. / Dann steht er auf." being one random example. This is all based on the rules on verb placement, the rest follows suit.

Comment: The verb has to come in second position. Compare these sentences. The finite verb is always in second position. "(1)Er (2)geht (3)dann (4)spielen." - "(1)Dann (2)geht (3)er (4)spielen". - "(1) Spielen (2)geht (3)er (4)dann." Read on here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order.

Comment: And just for the sake of completeness: V2 (verb in second postion) is for main clauses. Subjunctive clauses are SOV (verb goes in last place) and yes-no questions are V1 (verb in first place). Read on [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24723/when-does-a-verb-come-second) for example. Any basic grammar book should explain this system in detail.

Comment: Nice (and somewhat funny) explanation [here](https://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/con_06.html)